# How to send Updated data after every 5 mints service to activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I have added a service class in my activity I am getting updated location from backend in every 5 seconds but I don't know how to send updated location lat long from service to activity here is my service class :

```
public class DriverLocationService extends Service   {
BackgroundService service;
private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
private static String LOG_TAG = "BoundService";
String latDriver, longDriver;
public static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onRebind");
    super.onRebind(intent);
}
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onUnbind");
    return true;
}




@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (!service.isRunning()) {
        service.start();
        service.isRunning = true;

        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null){

        }

    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    service = new BackgroundService();
    Log.d("CREATED>>>>", "Created");
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (service.isRunning) {
        service.interrupt();
        service.isRunning = false;
        service = null;
    }
}
class BackgroundService extends Thread {
    public boolean isRunning = false;
    public long milliSecs = 5000;

    Runnable runTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    Log.d("HANDLER_RUNNABLE>>>>", "HANDLER");
                    startTracking();
                    Thread.sleep(milliSecs);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        runTask.run();
    }

    public void startTracking(){
        ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitManager.getInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<TrackResponse> call = apiInterface.checkTruckLocation(TruckApplication.ReadIntPreferences(SharedPrefData.PREF_BOOKING_ID) );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TrackResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TrackResponse> call, Response<TrackResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    TrackResponse trackResponse  = response.body();
                    assert trackResponse != null;
                    if (trackResponse.getSuccess()) {

                        if (trackResponse.getMessage().equals("Tracking start")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            latDriver =  trackResponse.getTruckLocation().getLat();
                            longDriver =  trackResponse.getTruckLocation().getLong();
                            Log.d("@@LAT2", latDriver);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getTruckLocation().getLat(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if (trackResponse.getMessage().equals("Tracking completed")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             onDestroy();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TrackResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error", t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });
    }

}

public String getLatLong() {

    double lat= Double.parseDouble(latDriver);
    double longD= Double.parseDouble(longDriver);
    return lat + ":" + longD ;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public DriverLocationService getService() {
        return DriverLocationService.this;
    }
}

}
```

and here is my activity where I want to update lat-long

```
  public class ShowDriverLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

DriverLocationService mBoundService;
boolean mServiceBound = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_driver_location);


    if (mServiceBound) {
        Toast.makeText(mBoundService, mBoundService.getLatLong(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverLocationService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mServiceBound) {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mServiceBound = false;
    }
}
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServiceBound = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
       DriverLocationService.MyBinder myBinder = (DriverLocationService.MyBinder) service;
        mBoundService = myBinder.getService();
        mServiceBound = true;
    }
  };
   }
```

please response me I would appreciate every answer thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can register a custom broadcast reciever in your activity and then simply publish broadcast from you service to the activity.

Comment: will this update lat long in my activity in every 5 sec as I am getting in service

Answer (score 1):

in your DriverLocationService create the function sendLocation(Context context, long location)

```
private void sendLocation(Context context, long location) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("can.be.any.your.string.constant");
    intent.putExtra("your.location.data.identifier", location);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

next
in your Activity add BroadcastReceiver

```
private LocationReceiver receiver;
private IntentFilter filter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    receiver = new LocationReceiver();
    filter = new IntentFilter("can.be.any.your.string.constant");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

private class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //here the **location** will contain your data
        long location = intent.getLongExtra("your.location.data.identifier", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: where I need to pass this method  sendLocation

Comment: @bugfreerammohan add this method in your service

Answer (score 0):

- The best approach is to set Listener from activity to service.
- Another solution is to use broadcast receiver and send broadcasts from service to activity.

Listener approach is better since you already use service connector, broadcast approach is little bit over engineering in the case if you use service connector.